# Want: Different volume for headset compared to speakers in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio

I need the windows volume to be a lot louder when using speakers compared to using headphones. When I plug in headphones my ears die from the "you have plugged in headphones"-sound, and when I plug them out I cannot hear a thing from the speakers.

Automatically setting volume to a preset value when switching from headphones to speakers and another for speakers to headphones is fine.

Is there a way to do this on windows 10?

Comment: Get a headset that has separate volume control

Comment: I'm using QC25. I'm not going to change headset. Is there something I could use between it and the computer?

Answer (score 0):

check this out
http://www.walmart.com/ip/Koss-In-Line-Headphone-Volume-Control/11051681

because i need to give you a longer answer full of garbage